# I think I am doing this wrong, won't copy to relative path

Tags: c#

```
public void Save_Token(string _Token)
{
    var Token_Location = @".\token.txt";

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Token_Location))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(_Token);
    }
}
```

I tried to get the token from the api (json) and I deserialized and saved it. I would like to write to the file to save for later. But I want this application to be ran on anyone's PC. So I don't want to use the full path.

I also tried

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,Token_Location);
```

still nothing is written, unless I use the full path.

Comment: Can you show your full path so that I can get more details about your question. I tried this in console app and it works fine.

Comment: Your code will try to create the file in the current working directory, which by default is the folder from which the .exe was run. It's possible the the .exe file is in a folder where the user doesn't have write permissions (e.g. under "C:\Program Files (x86)") in which case it won't be able to write the file. Anyway, you should check where the current working directory is: Add some debug output to print the value returned from a call to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and see if that's what you expected.

Comment: Use [Process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), set a filter for `Path`, `contains`, `token.txt` and then run your program. Probably the current directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: Easier still, output the result of `Directory. GetCurrentDirectory()` to a log file/the console or check it at a breakpoint in your program just before your code to write the file executes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 3):

You can't guarantee that the current user has write access to the folder from where the file is executed. There is a special folder (APP_DATA) that applications are supposed to use when storing user data on a computer:

```
public void Save_Token(string _Token)
{
    var tokenDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "YourCompanyOrOrganizationName");
    var tokenFile = Path.Combine(tokenDirectory, "token.txt");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tokenDirectory);
    File.WriteAllText(tokenFile, _Token);
}
```

Your file will then be stored in a path like `"C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\YourCompanyOrOrganizationName\token.txt"`

---

It is generally a bad idea to use a relative path in software source code because the "current working directory" of the process that the relative path is relative to can change over the runtime of the application.

Activities like showing a file open dialog or using a third-party component can unexpectedly change the current working directory so that it is dangerous to assume a certain current working directory.

Comment: While true, it isn't clear that the OP wants to write to "some directory they can write to" instead of a specific directory. This isn't a generally accurate answer as the question stands right now.

Comment: @EricJ. I think this is the correct answer, re: from the OP: _"But I want this application to be ran on anyone's PC. So I don't want to use the full path."_ The `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` directory is a great candidate for this use case, IMO.